# How to use HTML checkbox values to determine which php page to go?

Tags: php, html, forms, file

I have a project where I need to take values from an html checkbox to determine which page I need to go to. I coded like this but that is not really working.

```
<?php

    $db_host = 'localhost'; // Server Name
    $db_user = 'root'; // Username
    $db_pass = ''; // Password
    $db_name = 'assign'; // Database Name

    $conn = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);
    if (!$conn) {
        die ('Failed to connect to MySQL: ' . mysqli_connect_error());  
    }
?>


<html>

<body>
    <div class="form-style-8">
    <center><h2>Make a Choice</h2></center>
    <form action="/action_page.php">
      <input type="checkbox" name="chc" value="bat"> Batting<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chc" value="bwl"> Bowling<br>
      <input type="checkbox" name="chc" value="fld"> Fielding<br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    </div>
</body>


<?php

    if($_POST['chc'] == 'bat'){

    echo '<a href="Attatchment 1.php">Batting</a>';

    }
?>
</html>
```

If someone can help me understand how I can just open the php page with the checkbox ticking Batting, I believe I can finish the rest.

Comment: Use a URL for a page that exists.

Comment: are you saying that the file `"Attatchment 1.php"` does not exist?

Comment: *"But it keeps saying my "The requested URL was not found on this server. The link on the referring page seems to be wrong or outdated."* - Seems self-explanatory; check your file name and the path to it.

Comment: you can add an attribute to the checkboxes and access that value to determine the url you wish to go to

Comment: Forms default to a GET method when POST isn't implied.

Comment: I have the "Attatchment 1.php" file on the same folder as the the folder of this. But my problem isn't on there. I had the output php only echoing a messege and it still shows the error.